# File Monitor For Windows CE/Mobile

Tags: windows-mobile, windows-ce, file-monitoring

Is there a tool that will show me what files have changed over a period of time on either a Windows CE or Windows Mobile device? The reason I want this is I am trying to figure out exactly where IE history is stored. I was going to start the file watcher, delete my history, and then see what has changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a software app that resembles Filemon for full blown windows called CEMon. You can get it here:

http://mobile.butterscotch.com/preview/32476/CEMon

Comment: I did not try this out because I solved my problem without it, but it looks to be what I asked for...

Answer (score 0):

I saw your question about this topic in SO. I think it is possible that IE history is saved in the Windows Registry. I was going to recommend you to use "[Remote Registry Editor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms894590.aspx)" provided with Visual Studio in order to take two screen shots of the registry, after and before doing some browsing. Then you can use a diff tool ([winmerge](http://winmerge.org/) for example) to locate the registry keys that where changed.