# Where is Internet Explorer history stored on Windows CE or Windows Mobile

Tags: internet-explorer, windows-mobile, windows-ce, history

Where is Internet Explorer history stored on a Windows CE or Windows Mobile device? I am looking for the file or registry location, not just how to see it from IE.

Comment: possible duplicate of [File Monitor For Windows CE/Mobile](http://superuser.com/questions/283149/file-monitor-for-windows-ce-mobile)

Comment: I have absolutely zero experience with Windows CE (I'm an android user) , but in regular windows it's stored in "C:\Users\<your name>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\History".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that it is in HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders\My Documents\IE\History

Comment: Thanks! That registry key contained entries that give file paths for different things including internet history. The path it showed for history was Windows/Profiles/guest/History. In that folder I found a subfolder called History.IE5 which contains index.dat. It is not a clear text file but parts of it are in clear text and start with visited:URL. Hopefully I can parse it.